# ewsExchangeAPI Send Email Performance Issue

Tags: exchangewebservices

We planned to migrate the Old Outlook MAPI Logic to EWS Exchange API to send email. I have tested the performance of sending email by triggering 1500 emails (looped) with the attachment of 256 kb PDF File.

For One email it is taking 5 to 6 seconds and overall it is taking 2 hours to send all 1500 emails.
But in other side using Outlook MAPI just taking 45 Minutes to send all 1500 emails.

Am just using basic send email method not much logic added as like below (not an actual code I used).

//Create the email message.

```
        EmailMessage message = new EmailMessage(service); 
        message.Subject = "Message with Attachments"; 
        message.Body = "This message contains one item attachment."; 
        message.ToRecipients.Add(UserData.EmailAddress);  

        //Create another item and use it as an attachment. 
        ItemAttachment<EmailMessage> itemAttachment1 =  message.Attachments.AddItemAttachment<EmailMessage>(); 
        itemAttachment1.Name = "Attached Message Item"; 
        itemAttachment1.Item.Subject = "Message Item Subject"; 
        itemAttachment1.Item.Body = "Message Item Body"; 
        itemAttachment1.Item.ToRecipients.Add(UserData.EmailAddress); 

        message.SendAndSaveCopy();
```

Is this the API performance or I need to do some logic to send the email even faster.. Please suggest..
Thanks,
Gunasekaran Sambandhan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry All,

There was a problem in my code. I just modified the way of call from consuming application, as well as a slight change in my .NET COM INTERFACE LIBRARY.

In my case VB 6.0 is the consuming Application.

.NET COM INTERFACE LIBRARY

I just modified the class representation in a way that:

1. Create Exchange Web service instance method
2. Send email

From VB 6.0 Application:

1. Call The Create Exchange Web service instance method
2. loop thru 1500 emails & call Send email with details

Just a basic discipline that has to be followed but I didn't so I got performance issue. Now I rectified myself & now it is working better that Outlook MAPI. (i.e. Now EWS Only takes 15 minutes)

Thanks,
Gunasekaran Sambandhan